# background-image não altera no arquivo CSS no servidor

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho um bakckground num arquivo CSS que funciona bem no browser, mas quando coloco no servidor WAMP as alterações no CSS não acontecem. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Na Index

`<link href="estilo.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css">`

No CSS

```
body {
    border:0px solid red; /* borda de controle para programar */
    background-image: url('imagens/GrupoOficiaLCOR_TR25.png'), /*primeira imagem com transparência */
        url('imagens/ruido.png'),/*segunda imagem com transparencia */
        linear-gradient(45deg, #000,#FFF);
    background-attachment: fixed; /* fixa a imagem de fundo */
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif; /* tudo dentro do body terá esta família de fontes */
    overflow-x: hidden;  /* remove barra de rolagem horizontal */
    height: 100%;
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Já verificou se a imagem está no caminho correto? Verifica pressionando F12 no browser (na aba Console ou Network).

Comment: Provavelmente é o cache